# How to set ace editor to full screen using ng2-ace-editor

Tags: angular, ace-editor

In my ace editor I need a functionality when I click toggle full screen button then the editor need to show in full screen.

Note: Im using ng2-ace-editor in angular 6

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ace-editor [(text)]="text" [mode]="'javascript'" [options]="options" 
[readOnly]="false" [autoUpdateContent]="true"
[durationBeforeCallback]="1000" (textChanged)="onChange($event)" style="position: absolute;
top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: auto;"></div>
```